# Can I tell to a local graph node (the graph) to not scan blocks on initialization?

Tags: hardhat, ganache, the-graph, subgraph

I'm running a node graph locally using [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/en/).

I connected it to a HardHat network.

As soon as I run the docker-compose I noticed that the graph starts scanning the whole blockchain history.

Can I set something in the configuration in order to tell to the graph to NOT start scanning from the genesis block but from the latest one or from a specific one that I want?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find anything on how to force to The Graph to not start scanning as soon as it starts **BUT** there is the possibility to configure the genesis block.

In [the docs](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node/blob/master/docs/environment-variables.md) I found the variable GRAPH_ETHEREUM_GENESIS_BLOCK_NUMBER that is used for this purpose.

This allows you to don't start scanning from the 0 block, very useful when testing (which is exactly the reason why I did not want the graph to start scanning all the time that is started).

Comment: You can also use `startBlock` for the smart contracts that you want to track. That way you can tell the graph to start indexing from that block number.